# Signum function question

Tags: calculus

The sum of all values of $a$ for which $$f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}\left((x-a)(x-1)(x+1)\right),$$ $x\in \mathbb{R}$, has exactly two points of discontinuity, is:
$(A)-2$

$(B)-1$

$(C)0$

$(D)3$

I could not attempt because signum function confuses me lot.Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Is that supposed to be $\mathrm{sgn} ((x-a)(x-1)(x+1))$?

Comment: Ok sir,i corrected it.

Comment: [Read more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), @VarunIyer.

Comment: @ Varun sgn stands for signum a.k.a sign, for a given $x$ it is defined as: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/c/1/2/c12b404a34258107935dde5f88aaf7a3.png

Comment: I have read this wiki page but still could not solve it.Some hints will help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For there to be two points of discontinuity, $a$ must equal either $-1$ or $1$. $$\therefore \sum_{ \text{ such } a} a = -1 + 1 = 0 $$

Comment: It would be nice if you give an explanation as well.

Comment: @AshutoshGupta: The $(x-a)$ term introduces another root at $a$ i.e. another change of sign around $a$. For there to only be two changes of sign, $a$ must coincide with the other roots of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
(x-a)(x-1)(x+1)=(x-a)(x^2-1)
$$
and $x^2-1$ change sign in $x=\pm1$ (exactly two points). The factor $x-a$ introduce one other  change of sign if $a \ne \pm 1$, so you have two chiange of sign only if $a=\pm1$